# React Native Calendar markedDates

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-calendars

In react native calendar there are markedDates which are providing the planned events. The code for a manual entry is following:
markedDates={{
    '2012-05-16': {selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: 'blue'},
    '2012-05-17': {marked: true},
    '2012-05-18': {marked: true, dotColor: 'red', activeOpacity: 0},
    '2012-05-19': {disabled: true, disableTouchEvent: true}
  }}
What do I have to do to set the markedDates dynamically out of an array?

That is the line from the render():
markedDates={this.state.selectedDate, this.state.markedDates}

This is executed in componentDidMount:
var selectedDate = {}
selectedDate[dateString] = { selected: true, selectedColor: '#c4c4c4', text: { color: 'black' } }
this.setState({
            selectedDate: selectedDate
        })

[Dynamically mark dates in react-native-calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59243865/dynamically-mark-dates-in-react-native-calendars/61460444?noredirect=1#comment108721440_61460444)
This is a link to a similar question but it doesn't really answer it or I don't understand the answer. Both is possible

Comment: share your array or your source code or check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59602003/9432559

Comment: @SDushan thanks for the link. What is in the moment file?

Comment: ```moment``` is a library that handles dates & times -https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @SDushan is there a way to combine you code with the following code? [this.state.selected]: {
selected: true, selectedColor: '#c4c4c4',
text: {
color: 'black'
 }
 }

Comment: you have to convert your data according to the above structure. if you need more help, share your code.

Comment: I did this but when I try to display the data like markedDates={this.state.selectedDate, this.state.markedDates} it onla shows the selectedDate value

Comment: could you share your values of ```state```.

Comment: this.state = {
            selected: undefined,
            today: '',
            todaydatestate: '',
            datestringglob: '',
            markedDates: {},
            selectedDate: {},
            eventprogram: [],
            eventday: 'Heute',
            todayreal: ''
        };

Comment: @SDushan here is the value of the state. var selectedDate = {}
        selectedDate[dateString] = { selected: true, selectedColor: '#c4c4c4', text: { color: 'black' } }

Comment: could you update your question with the current code.

Comment: i'm looking for the same answer, i got a set of dates (holidays and other days) in a json structure from an api, my problem is that i'm not entirely sure how to set every day from this json to have a specific color like, json array -> {textColor: 'red', {backgroundColor: 'blue} for every day coming from this api

Answer (score 2):

with an array who looks like

```
['yyyy-mm-dd','yyyy-mm-dd','yyyy-mm-dd']
```

you can just map on it like that :

```
var customMarkedDates = {};
var arrayOfDates =  ['2020-11-06','2020-11-25','2020-08-12'];
arrayOfDates.map((day) => {
          customMarkedDates[day] = {
            customStyles: {
              container: {
                backgroundColor: "red",
              },
              text: {
                color: "white",
                fontWeight: "bold",
              },
            },
          };
        });

this.setState({customMarkedDates: customMarkedDates})
```

Then you can call it in your calendar like `markedDates={this.state.customMarkedDates}` and change it when you need to.